# 2D Animation: Drawing new strokes makes the existing layer disappear?

Tags: animation, 2d

Not sure why this is suddenly happening but when I draw any new strokes/fills (the pink blob in the example photo), it deletes the previous strokes/fills on that layer (the sand colored layer in the top photo). How do I fix this?

I've also tried creating a new empty grease pencil as the top layer but when I draw a colored fill (no stroke), it gives a weird thin white line as a stroke.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lol i figured it out. my lines and fills were locked.

[image]